# How to checkout a clone repository in git

Tags: git, github

I have created a git repository using the windows GitHub client.

I want to create a new check out of that repository on my harddrive. I want to be able to do a commit from one repository, and do and pull from the other to make sure that commit didn't miss anything or break anything.

But using github client I only have the options of Add, Create, and Clone.

None of these seem to check out a repository from a URL. Is this not possible?

In fact it seems like Add and Create are the exact same thing...

Comment: I guess the Github client is designed to clone from Github, not a local repository. If you really wanted to do this, I would install cygwin & git, and use the command line interface.

Comment: Or git shell, which is easier and faster to install than cygwin. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell

Comment: Do you mean you're using git for desktop (the successor to git for windows)?

Comment: Sounds like what you really want to do is set up some continuous integration server that builds/tests your application whenever you push new commits.

Answer (score 0):

**Clone** = **Init** + **Add Remote** (using URL) + **Pull**.

In your case it looks like you did only **Init**.

If it's true than now you need just to **Add Remote** and **Pull**.

Comment: I want to have another check out of repository Foo on my local machine. When in Github client I got clone repository , and select Foo, GitHub client tells me "this repository has already been added

Comment: @ScottF I didn't quite get what is the location of that repo. Is it on server (GitHub I guess)? Is it in your filesystem? How do you select "Foo" (in clone dialog as far as I understood)? Using URL to that repo on GitHub? Using filesystem reference to repo dir? May be you're trying to clone to same dir (the one that is already "mapped" to remote repo).

Comment: I have repository Foo on local file system. I then added it to github. I now want to pull another copy of Foo from github down to a different location locally.

Comment: @ScottF In such case you need a new EMPTY dir. Just clone to that dir with GutHub repo url.